# Facebook App Center Submission: Facebook Login Inactivity

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-app-center

I cannot find this anywhere on Google and was hoping someone might help me.
My Problem is that I'm submitting a game to FB App Center and it just doesnt allow me to submit, giving this error:

[image: Facebook error]

I believe this error is a false positive, since I just tested logging in on my iPad 3, which obviously runs iOS.
I also have a Android-version and I dont see FB complaining about that.

The game in question is already out there in production, on request I can post links (I dont want to make it look like spam)

By the way, the game runs on the Unity Facebook SDK version 5.1
I can provide more info if needed. Thanks a lot!

**Update** Added more info

When logging the callback, I even get a success response:

```
FacebookDidLogin > FBresult: {"is_logged_in":true,"user_id":"100002273765146","access_token":"CAAVCkhjK8KgBAD.....","access_token_expires_at":"07/22/2014 10:47:57"}
```

Another thing worth noting is that in the insights, frankly there are no iOS accepted logins visible. Which is really weird because I just did.

**Figure 1:** There are iOS views
[image: There are iOS views]

**Figure 2:** No iOS-acceptations but there should be at least 1
[image: No iOS-acceptations but there should be at least 1]

Comment: Please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I Guess I could do that, I assumed this wasnt a bug at all.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/239266109607736/ got it right here!

Comment: @PeterWillemsen how did you manage to get past this issue? I get the same message when trying to submit for FB approval. I looked on the bug you opened at FB team but it is still not clear what the problem is. Just as in your case, I have done many logins already and the insight tab shows many logins.